# Display list of attributes from specific category?

Tags: category, attributes

I'm working on navigation menu in custom theme Magento web site. I would like to display a list of the specified attribute name (brand) from the specific category. The mentioned navigation menu is on the index/home page.

For example, I have a category name: "Laptops for everyday use", and I have a custom attribute name "brand_name". I would like to be able to display this as:

Laptops for everyday use:
- Asus
- Acer
- Apple
etc...

Comment: is this category attribute?

Comment: yes, attribute name is "brand_name". This is custom attribute I have made.

Comment: is this category type attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by some changes at observer class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer`

This class render the menu

**Change at Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer:**

Goto function `_addCategoriesToMenu()` and here you have find the `category  name` has been set. Find

```
   $categoryData = array(
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => $nodeId,
        'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
    );
```

Here change  at `name` index

```
  $categoryData = array(
            'name' => $category->getName().'-'. $category->getData('brand_name'),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
        );
```

**Note:**
if  `$category->getData('brand_name')` is not work then try this below  code which provide to data from resource model:

```
$category->getResource()->getAttribute('brand_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($category-)
```